# Optimal decision rules given a set of bimodal values

Tags: optimization, game-theory, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

Some patients have two possible illnesses ; to determine which illness a patient has, we make a test (only once) that will result **in one of five outcomes**, which have the following conditional probabilities :
$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{Outcome} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
P(\text{outcome}\, |\,\text{illness 1}) & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.15 & 0.1 & 0.05 \\
P(\text{outcome} \, |\,\text{illness 2}) & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.4 & 0.15 & 0.05 \\
\end{array}
 $$
We want to minimize the probability of a type II error (diagnosing illness 1 to a patient with illness 2) to the constraint that the probability of a type I error (diagnosing illness 2 to a patient with illness 1) is 5% or less. 
What is the optimal decision rule?

**My attempt**

I thought maybe we could determine $n_1$, $n_2$, ..., $n_5$, such that, for example, if the result of the patient is outcome $i$ with value $v_i$ and with $v_i> n_i$, we choose the illness with the associated outcome with (conditional) probability higher than $n_i$.

To determine those $n_1$, $n_2$, ..., $n_5$, maybe we can use the 
chi-squared test, which will give the first constraint : 
$$ \frac{(n_1-0.4)^2}{0.4^2}+ \frac{(n_2-0.3)^2}{0.3^2}+ \frac{(n_3-0.15)^2}{0.15^2}+ \frac{(n_4-0.1)^2}{0.1^2}+ \frac{(n_5-0.05)^2}{0.05^2}<9.4877$$
(the last value being related to $\chi_4^2$)
under which we want to minimize : 
$$ \frac{(n_1-0.3)^2}{0.3^2}+ \frac{(n_2-0.1)^2}{0.1^2}+ \frac{(n_3-0.4)^2}{0.4^2}+ \frac{(n_4-0.15)^2}{0.15^2}+ \frac{(n_5-0.05)^2}{0.05^2}$$
(but I don't know, up until now, how to compute such of constrained minimization).

Is the use of the chi-squared test in that situation relevant? (Knowing additionally that the chi-squared test is asymptotic, and we do to the patient a single test...)

If what I tried makes sense, how to compute the constrained minimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_i$ be the probability such that if the outcome is $i$, you diagnose illness 2 with probability $p_i$ (so if the test outcome is $i$, you draw a uniform random variable from $[0,1]$, and pronounce illness 2 if the random variable is less than $p_i$).

The probability on a type I error is $0.4 p_1 + 0.3 p_2 + 0.15 p_3 + 0.1 p_4 + 0.05 p_5$.

The probability on a type II error is $0.3(1-p_1) + 0.1(1-p_2) + 0.4(1-p_3) + 0.15(1-p_4) + 0.05(1-p_5)$.

This results in the following linear optimization problem:
$$\begin{align}
\min \quad & 0.3(1-p_1) + 0.1(1-p_2) + 0.4(1-p_3) + 0.15(1-p_4) + 0.05(1-p_5) \\
\text{such that} \quad & 0.4 p_1 + 0.3 p_2 + 0.15 p_3 + 0.1 p_4 + 0.05 p_5 \leq 0.05 \\
&0 \leq p_i \leq 1
\end{align}$$
This problem is readily solved with YALMIP:

```
p = sdpvar(5,1);
a=[0.4 0.3 0.15 0.1 0.05; 0.3 0.1 0.4 0.15 0.05];
objective = a(2,:) * (1-p);
constraints = [a(1,:)*p <= 0.05; 0 <= p; p <= 1];
optimize(constraints,objective);
```

the solution is $p_1=p_2=p_4=p_5=0$, $p_3 = 1/3$.

Comment: "and pronounce illness 2 if the random variable is less than $p_i$" : but  for outcome 3, the conditional probability for illness 2 is higher than for illness 1, isn't contradictory with the rule you stated? Moreover, every $p_i$ are $0$, except that very $p_3$, and again, if the outcome is, for example less then 0.1, why choosing illness 2 and not illness 1? It sounds to me a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: So maybe it is better to use your idea with $p_1$, $p_2$, $1-p_3$, $p_4$, $p_5$ ?

Comment: @Netchaiev If you use $p_3 = 2/3$, the type I error is too high. I still stand by my answer.

Comment: Ok, I see (I couldn't try by myself, since I wasn't able to run your code : my matlab says to me : "Undefined function 'yalmip' for input arguments of type 'char'.
Error in sdpvar (line 518)
[mt,variabletype,hashed_monoms,current_hash] = yalmip('monomtable');"

Comment: @Netchaiev see https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/installation/ for installation instructions

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link!